# LoRa Node registrating at LoRa Gateway

Tags: iot, arduino-uno, lora

I am starting a project for my university and starting to play around with the [LoRa stuff](http://www.dragino.com/products/lora/item/120-lora-iot-kit.html), working through this [pdf](http://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/UserManual/LG01_LoRa_Gateway_User_Manual.pdf) , filled with some examples.

I've used the code examples from page 47 ([Client](https://github.com/dragino/Arduino-Profile-Examples/blob/master/libraries/Dragino/examples/IoTServer/ThingSpeak/dht11_client/dht11_client.ino), [Server](https://github.com/dragino/Arduino-Profile-Examples/blob/master/libraries/Dragino/examples/IoTServer/ThingSpeak/LG01_ThingSpeak_RESTful_Single_Data/LG01_ThingSpeak_RESTful_Single_Data.ino)). It's working fine but I don't understand how the node is registering at the gateway. I mean, where is the part in the code?

Answer (score 4):

The links you have posted to Github appear to be using the RFM95 module in a peer to peer fashion rather than utilising LoRaWAN style communication. Can I suggest you try using the LoRa LMIC library instead, this has a full implementation of LoRaWAN and can be used with TheThingsNetwork & RFM95 modules - https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic.

As for the gateway I am unsure of the Dragino gateway hardware / software, however I believe they are capable of acting as a Single Channel Gateway / Packet Forwarder. There is a decent forum thread here discussing how to use the Dragino gateway with TTN, https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/dragino-gateway/6154 and the Dragino wiki has a comprehensive how to guide  http://wiki.dragino.com/index.php?title=Connect_to_TTN. However there are short comings with single channel gateways, and some do not support downstream messages, so depending on your use case this may or may not be so useful.

If you can describe more in depth your use case I'd be keen to offer up more advice / ideas, I use LoRa a fair bit, but I only have experience with the Arduino Dragino hats not their gateway.